# Trouble updating Eclipse 4.2.1

Tags: eclipse

I am unable to update Eclipse from `Help > Check for Updates`.

Error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  org.eclipse.actf.visualization.ui.pdt.feature.group [1.0.2.R201302130546] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
```

Environment:

```
OS X version: 10.8.3
```

Eclipse:

```
Eclipse Platform
Version: 4.2.1
Build id: M20120914-1800
```

I have no idea how to solve this. All of a sudden it seems like *every component* needs updating, at the same time none of them update properly.

By "every component", I mean **every component**:

```
Acceleo SDK 3.3.2.201302130808
ACTF Visualization Extension for PDT Feature    1.0.2.R201302130546
ACTF Visualization Extension for WST Feature    1.0.2.R201302130546
ACTF Visualization Feature  1.0.2.R201302130546
ACTF Visualization SDK Feature  1.0.2.R201302130546
BIRT Framework  4.2.2.v201301281649-ClBI9nGZcVSofEz-Xuz0n-ruJtUm
C/C++ Development Tools SDK 8.1.2.201302132326
C/C++ Library API Documentation Hover Help  1.0.0.201302051708
ChangeLog Management Tools  2.8.0.201302051708
ChangeLog Management Tools for Java 2.8.0.201302051708
Code Recommenders Developer Tools   1.0.3.v20130211-0152-b208
Custom Widget Toolkit   0.9.0.201303141537
Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink DBWS Support  1.1.102.v201301101606-797EBpCcNBHLEeHXGVaV4KKI
Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink JAXB Support  1.3.2.v201301092252-777B5BgJ9EJAgHNGrMm1f9e
Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink JPA Support   3.2.2.v201301082148-7K7J78EVVFNVHz0NgOXgX4KKI
Dali Java Persistence Tools - JAXB Support  1.2.2.v201301082148-56ACAkF7BG7WDLFEEF
Dali Java Persistence Tools - JPA Diagram Editor    1.1.2.v201301082148-408c9oB58C5FCB77B5
Dali Java Persistence Tools - JPA Support   3.2.2.v201301091616-7U7K8qFC7sRdwVKaof36y4KKI
Data Tools Platform Enablement Extender SDK 1.10.2.v201209181447-7I9e7XFE9JgB80wJRUvMfJanCn7b
Data Tools Platform Extender SDK    1.10.2.v201209181447-7PAO7gFEpPZ58s9hZvnBQRrZbbiG
Eclipse BIRT Chart Context Sensitive Help Documentation 4.2.2.v201210101433-5117w312413162211
Eclipse BIRT Context Sensitive Help Documentation   4.2.2.v201210101433-5117w312321212544
Eclipse BIRT Documentation  4.2.2.v201210101433-5117w312413162211
Eclipse BIRT Example    4.2.2.v201210101433-7T7D7DDZRDKRKELIKjed
Eclipse BIRT Source Feature 4.2.2.v201301281649-ClBI9nGZcVSofEz-Xuz0n-ruJtUm
Eclipse EGit    2.2.0.201212191850-r
Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.4.2.v201301240600-7b7JINbFSK2WM3QNAEr799V-TyUp
Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools    3.4.2.v201209272000-7F7DFSpC26SrlX9qoilV1RGQC9ivZy86-bz-IBHe
Eclipse JGit    2.2.0.201212191850-r
Eclipse JGit Command Line Interface 2.2.0.201212191850-r
Eclipse Platform    4.2.2.M20130204-1200
Eclipse Platform SDK    4.2.2.M20130204-1200
Eclipse SDK 4.2.2.M20130204-1200
Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.4.2.v201211061806-7O7MFu3EMkBK01NbrfU9ATE5cdZFz-OoeYjaI4d2
Eclipse XML Editors and Tools   3.4.2.v201211061806-7H7GFeJDxumUrsn5qkiQgOEhsz0p60HAmPyU6VX
Eclipse XSL Developer Tools 1.3.200.v201212131556-7T7ZFUbFIqUoJvvaKoCpRBIaGVOf
EGit Plug-in Import Support 2.2.0.201212191850-r
EMF Compare 1.3.3.v20130213-0806
EMF Compare SDK 1.3.3.v20130213-0806
Equinox Target Components   3.8.0.v20121212-203907-7M7fA78g4_y-gDvtH0ZcFvhMPDZJ
Fortran Development Tools (Photran) 8.0.4.201302122310
Graphical Editing Framework GEF Examples    3.9.0.201212170307
Graphical Editing Framework GEF SDK 3.9.0.201212170307
Graphical Modeling Framework (GMF) Runtime  1.6.2.201302122140
Graphical Modeling Framework (GMF) Runtime Examples 1.6.2.201302122140
Graphical Modeling Framework (GMF) Runtime SDK  1.6.2.201302122140
Graphical Modeling Framework (GMF) Tooling  3.0.2.201301191623
Graphical Modeling Framework (GMF) Tooling - Runtime Extensions 3.0.2.201301191623
Graphical Modeling Framework (GMF) Tooling SDK  3.0.2.201301191623
JavaServer Faces Tools (JSF) Project    3.5.0.v201301161500-7E7U-F9JgLWrLWXMXBLL
JAX-WS Tools    1.2.1.v201301072322-7E7AF72F8NcJSbKkQAUoWl
JST Server Adapters 3.2.201.v20130123_1813-20A87w31241234a2924
JST Server Adapters Extensions  3.3.102.v20130108_1103-777HFL7CcNBDnBcIVFHFD8
m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.0.20130129-0926
m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.3.0.20130129-0926
MoDisco SDK (Incubation)    0.10.2.201301291118
Nebula CalendarCombo Widget 1.0.0.201303141537
Nebula CDateTime Widget 0.14.0.201303141537
Nebula CompositeTable Widget    1.0.0.201303141537
Nebula Examples View Feature    1.0.4.201303141537
Nebula TableCombo Widget    1.0.0.201303141537
Nebula Widgets Examples 1.0.4.201303141537
Net4j Signalling Platform SDK   4.1.2.v20121030-0624
ObjectAid Class Diagram 1.1.1
OCL End User SDK    4.0.2.v20130130-1128
OCL Examples and Editors    3.2.2.v20130130-1128
Operational QVT SDK 3.2.2.v20130128-1651
Papyrus SDK Binaries (Incubation)   0.9.2.v201302131112
Parallel Tools Platform (PTP) End-User Runtime  6.0.4.201302122324
PyDev for Eclipse   2.7.3.2013031601
Rich Ajax Platform (RAP) Tools  1.5.2.20130205-2030
Scout RAP Target    3.8.2.201302111336
Scout Runtime   3.8.2.201302111336
Scout SDK   3.8.2.201302111336
Scout SDK RAP   3.8.2.201302111336
Subversive SVN Team Provider    1.0.0.I20130122-1700
Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources    1.0.0.I20130122-1700
UML2 Extender SDK   4.0.2.v20130114-0902
WAR Products (Incubation)   0.2.2.201212132117
Web Page Editor 2.4.0.v201301161500-479-9oB58E588N8K55
WST Server Adapters 3.2.203.v20130123_1813-7L3FA4CcNBGVCZL_l8OCG
Xpand SDK   1.3.0.v201302260541
XSD - XML Schema Definition SDK 2.8.2.v20130125-0826
... ... ...
```

If I follow the error message and try to manually disable `ACTF Visualization Extension for PDT Feature 1.0.2.R201302130546`, it tells me:

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  org.eclipse.actf.visualization.sdk.feature.group [1.0.2.R201302130546] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
```

If I disable `ACTF Visualization SDK Feature 1.0.2.R201302130546`, it tells me:

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  org.eclipse.actf.visualization.feature.group [1.0.2.R201302130546] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
```

... and so on...

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: EGit Plug-in Import Support 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.import.feature.group 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
  Software currently installed: EGit Project Set Support 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.egit.psf.feature.group 2.1.0.201209190230-r)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Git Team Provider Core 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
    Git Team Provider Core 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 2.1.0.201209190230-r)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EGit Plug-in Import 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.import 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
    To: package org.eclipse.egit.core.internal [2.2.0,2.3.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EGit Plug-in Import Support 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.import.feature.group 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
    To: org.eclipse.egit.import [2.2.0.201212191850-r]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EGit Project Set Support 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.egit.psf.feature.group 2.1.0.201209190230-r)
    To: org.eclipse.egit.core [2.1.0,2.2.0)
```

These are my (active) Available Software Sites:

```
buckminster-egf-juno/org.eclipse.egf.site   http://download.eclipse.org/egf/updates/juno/official/  EnabledCodePro AnalytiX http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/3.7    Enabled
Composite Artifact Repository   http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/acceleo/updates/releases/3.2   Enabled
DataNucleus http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/eclipse-update/    Enabled
DBViewer    http://www.ne.jp/asahi/zigen/home/plugin/dbviewer/  Enabled
EclEmma http://update.eclemma.org/  Enabled
Eclipse CheckStyle  http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/update/    Enabled
FindBugs    http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/ Enabled
Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)    http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 Enabled
Juno    http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/  Enabled
Juno    http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/201209280900  Enabled
Logback http://logback.qos.ch/p2/   Enabled
MercurialEclipse    http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable Enabled
Nebula Widgets  http://download.eclipse.org/technology/nebula/snapshot/ Enabled
ObjectAid UML Explorer  http://www.objectaid.com/update Enabled
PMD http://pmd.sf.net/eclipse   Enabled
PyDev   http://pydev.org/updates/   Enabled
QuickREx    http://www.bastian-bergerhoff.com/eclipse/features/ Enabled
soapUI  http://www.soapui.org/eclipse/update/   Enabled
The Eclipse Project Updates http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2 Enabled
Update Site http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/juno-site/   Enabled
Xtext All In One - Releases http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/  Enabled
YEdit   http://dadacoalition.org/yedit  Enabled
```

Comment: You have a lot of things there and they're not all tightly related, are they? Maybe going to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads and installing Eclipse for JEE Developers (for Web Developer Tools etc.) separately from Eclipse Modeling Tools (for BIRT etc.) would help. Short of that, I might consider binary search: select half the components for upgrade and see if that works; if so, do half of what remains; if not, attempt half of the set that failed; and so on.

Comment: I like how, by doing human-driven binary search, you are bringing some "science" to an otherwise random approach of "let's push this button and see if anything happens"! :) I am not criticising, in fact sometimes I do the same too.. and it's probably how we first found out which organs did what in the human body: by removing them and checking if the guys still breathed..

Comment: Of course reinstalling, with everything I have in this installation, would probably take 2 full days and not come out as well. It used to be my _perfect_ development environment.. for months.

Comment: I understand. I was in a similar situation with the Eclipse upgrade from 3 to 4. And the binary search approach to mysterious sites of failure was lore that I picked up from someone, maybe a friend, maybe freshman computer science, but I didn't figure it out for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall org.eclipse.egit.psf first. It is [no longer supported](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.2#Installation) and you cannot upgrade egit without uninstalling it. That should solve your third group of error messages (all containing "egit" somewhere).

Afterwards, I would try to *uninstall* all of the ACTF components. Your upgrade should be possible afterwards.

If all else fails, you can use File -> Export -> Install -> Items to file to export a *selection of currently installed plugins* and install those again in another clean Eclipse installation using File -> Import -> Install. That way you could get rid of some obscure plugins and reinstall in half an hour.

Comment: I did the uninstalls: 1) `org.eclipse.egit.psf.feature.group` 2) `org.eclipse.actf.visualization.ui.pdt.feature.group` `org.eclipse.actf.visualization.ui.wst.feature.group` `org.eclipse.actf.visualization.feature.group` `org.eclipse.actf.visualization.sdk.feature.group`, `org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group`, `org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.feature.group`, `org.eclipse.egit.import.feature.group`, `org.eclipse.egit.psf.feature.group` INDEED.. I was able to upgrade!!!!!!!

Comment: You are always so helpful.. and knowledgeable.. really GREAT!